# Ultra symmetrical line algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

I ran into special case where I need to produce ultra symmetrical line or ray in 2D grid in order from (x0, y0) through (x1, y1) like this:

```
void drawSymmetricalLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
    // loop and handle each (x, y)...
}
```

The actual problem lies in points where popular line drawing algorithms does NOT draw both coordinates (the other marked as x below) since it seems as thicken, which is desired in my case. Also performance is not important but simplicity.

Here is what I mean as ultra symmetrical lines:

```
ox   ooo
 oo     ooo


o    o
 o    o
  o   o
       o
```

Answer (score 4):

You can probably use [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) and modify it slightly so when the step change to move the draw position from one row to another you paint both the before and after pixels on the y-axis for the current x-axis.

Answer (score 3):

Render the line twice, once from p0 to p1 and again from p1 to p0.

Comment: This is what I do for symmetrical line of sight in games.

Answer (score 1):

If simplicity is preferred over performance, then write a recursive algorithm. At each step compute DX=X1-X0 and DY=Y1-Y0.

Stop recursion when DX=0 or DY=0 (in which case your line is vertical or horizontal).

Otherwise, compute the two "middle" end-points, according to the parity of DX and DY, and draw the two half lines recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) except when you plot a point at (x0+dx, y0+dy), also plot a point at (x1-dx, y1-dy). That way you ensure that it is symmetrical from both sides.

It's a little inefficient, but you said that doesn't matter.